# phonegap black screen ios

Tags: javascript, ios, xcode, debugging, cordova

I would like to launch a javascript cordova application in ios (library 2.1). This application don't have problems to works in Android.
But if I would like to launch the same in ios (I have just changed the cordova javascript library), I have just a black screen. It doesn't have problem's to built.

I have tested to launch the application in Safari and Firefox browser but I didn't have any javascript error. 
I have tested these methods

[Phonegap - Javascript debugging in Xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4827213/phonegap-javascript-debugging-in-xcode)

and this method

http://jaydata.org/blog/debugging-a-phonegap-application

and this

http://community.phonegap.com/nitobi/topics/ios_build_does_not_work_native_app_freezes_on_blank_screen_after_splash

but I didn't have error, only a black screen on the device.

I didn't have a big knowledge in phonegap with ios.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally I have resolve my problems to create a new cordova application.